# Zombies in bash

Tags: bash, process

Bash doesn't seem to create zombies.
It looks like the processes get immediately reaped when they get killed.

Can I make bash make zombies?

---

#### Why I'm asking:

I'd like to be able to safely kill a child process or safely `kill -9` it if it doesn't die within a certain period of time but I don't want to accidentally zap a process that isn't my child process. Zombie processes usually make it very easy and race-condition safe.

Comment: Maybe another idea... if you really want to protect from killing outside processes, check out cgroups. Call `unshare` to create a PID namespace, so that from within that process tree, the outside processes are isolated and inaccessible.

Comment: Use [job control](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#JOB_CONTROL) (as in, `kill -KILL %n` where `n` is the job number, and so on), instead of trying to circumvent it.

Comment: Great question!  An alternate approach to "why you're asking," though: have you considered the `timeout` command?

Answer (score 21):

To make a zombie process:

```
$ (sleep 1 & exec /bin/sleep 10)
```

This replace the shell which run `sleep 1` with `/bin/sleep 10` that won't know the `sleep 1` process terminated, so creating a zombie for 10 seconds.

---

I'm not sure what do you expect from killing a zombie process. A zombie process was already dead, you can not kill it.

Actually, you can make zombie processes disappear, but by killing its parent, not zombie processes themselves.

Comment: Reaped PIDs get recycled. The point of zombies is that they reserve PIDs until the parent acknowledges the death of its child by waiting on it. Without this, killing a pid can result in an accidental victim.

Comment: In C, you can be sure you won't make an accidental victim when you kill your child because until you've waited on that child, that child's PID cannot be recycled. I'd like to be able to have the same guarantee in the shell.

Answer (score 2):

Not so interesting answer:

```
$ (A=$BASHPID && ( kill -STOP $A ))

[1]+  Stopped                 ( A=$BASHPID && ( kill -STOP $A ) )

$ ps -C bash
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
29453 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
29593 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
29594 pts/0    00:00:00 bash <defunct>
```

Comment: How is this a zombie process? It just stopped. Also `$BASHPID` is `$$` I think.

Comment: `$BASHPID`  is **not** the same that `$$`. Try following code:
 `echo $$ $BASHPID ;echo  $(echo $$ $BASHPID)`. You can find more information in `man bash`.